# How to make zsh autocorrect ` to ~?

Tags: zsh, prezto

I regularly mistype `~/Desktop/files` as `` `/Desktop/files ``. Is there a way for zsh to help me autocorrect this? I am using the `prezto` zsh installation. Thanks.

Comment: I doubt you want this correction in general; ` is quite a useful character in shell programming...

Comment: ` `...` ` can, and should, be replaced with `$(...)`.

Comment: I have a similar problem; I mistype `~/` as `~?` regularly.